# how to get data from api response to display on label in swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, api, decode

I am trying to get API data to display in label i get api response successfully in model, how i can get response values in viewcontroller to show on label. here is the method to get json response

```
private textCode:CodeModel
private func load() {
    codeProvider.load(target: .myCode, withActivity: true) {[weak self] result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let response):
            print(response,"response here")
            self?.textCode = response
            self?.output.perform(action: .didLoad)
            case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
                
        }
    }
}
extension CodeModel: codeViewControllerOutput {
var displayable: DisplayableCode {
    DisplayableCode(user: textCode)
 }
```

in codeViewController class i am trying to call displayable

```
 private func fillFields() {
    let d = model.displayable
    codeLabl.text = d.someTextcode
}
```

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an
> Optional value

Comment: Use the debugger. Set breakpoints and watch variables. Likely an outlet is not connected

Comment: Which line/property has a nil value that it shouldn't, which throw the error?

Comment: DisplayableCode(user: code) here it is giving fatal error

Comment: it is the textCode model object

Comment: When is called `model.displayable` Has `print(response,"response here")` been printed yet?

Comment: _@Larme yes print response correct?. values are there in response in model class how i can get in viewcontroller class